# VLOOKUP value contained in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have 2 sheets with values like :

```
Sheet 1, column D : SUPER iPhone X 16GB
Sheet 2, column B : iPhone X
```

I would like, in Sheet 1, to display the matching value from Sheet 2 (in this example "iPhone X")

I have tried many Vlookup like this but cannot find the right one :

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&D6&"*";Sheet 2!B:B;1;FALSE)
```

As requested I have created a sample spreadsheet with 2 sheets and sample data you can test here :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OHsS5SyvzHvJaRtqKXVmCSSDeKA3iqX5JC2qE8WHPw0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your excel version? Show more sample data and expected output.

Comment: I am using Google sheets. Expected output would be "iPhone X" here for the row having as name "SUPER iPhone X 16GB". Basically I am trying to do IF (Sheet1, column D) value is contained in (Sheet2, column B) value, then return the (Sheet2, column B) value

Comment: I recommend that you share a link to a sample spreadsheet with realistic data located in the actual ranges they appear within your real-world sheet. Formulas are written around specifics, and we currently don't have many. There are a lot of factors involved, and the most efficient means of conveying them is to just let the volunteer contributors here see everything ourselves together in one place.

Comment: You are right @ErikTyler this is easier, I have created sample data and added the link in the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it into `B2`

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF(ISERROR(FIND(LOWER('Feuille 2'!B:B);LOWER(A2)));;'Feuille 2'!B:B);"select Col1 where Col1 is not null limit 1";0))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I have added a link to sample data in my original post and put your solution in B4 if you are willing to check

Comment: Modified. The cell you provided was `D6` but it is not correct.

Comment: Yes, it has changed in the sample data. I have checked your formula but could not get the results. It gives me "ERROR"

Comment: Changed the commas into semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&D6&"*"; 'Sheet 2'!B:B; 1; 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I have added a link to sample data in my original post and put your solution in B3 if you are willing to check

Comment: PO is asking for the opposite of `VLOOKUP`